# rabbitmqctl set_policy drops caret (^) anchor from regex pattern

Tags: powershell, regex, rabbitmq

I am running this from PowerShell, so I'm not sure if this would happen in a different environment (the regex itself just includes everything except for those starting with 'amq.').

When I run the following command, the '^' is dropped from the pattern:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy mirroring '^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$' '{"""ha-mode""":"""all"""}'
```

It outputs the following:

```
Setting policy "mirroring" for pattern "(?!(?:amq\\.)).+$" to "{\"ha-mode\":\"all\"}" with priority "0" ...
```

I've tried escaping it in different ways without any success. Interestingly, setting it from the web management plugin works fine.

**UPDATE**

The issue seems to be related to the `^` being a reserved character in batch files (I think), and not being quoted as far as the batch file is concerned (i.e. PS needs to pass in a quoted string for the pattern, but it was passing in the regex as-is). Any of the following work, based on [beatcracker](https://serverfault.com/users/270504/beatcracker)'s answer:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy mirroring '"^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$"' '{\"ha-mode\":\"all\"}'

rabbitmqctl --% set_policy mirroring "^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$" {\"ha-mode\":\"all\"}

rabbitmqctl @('set_policy','mirroring','"^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$"','{\"ha-mode\":\"all\"}')

Start-Process -FilePath 'rabbitmqctl' -ArgumentList 'set_policy mirroring "^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$" {\"ha-mode\":\"all\"}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PS 2.0 and higher:

> If you specify an array of values, it will automatically expand them
>   into separate parameters.

```
& rabbitmqctl @('set_policy mirroring', '^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$', '{ha-mode:all}')
```

> Using `Start-Process` cmdlet.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'rabbitmqctl' -ArgumentList 'set_policy mirroring ^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$ {ha-mode:all}'

# Same as above, shortened using aliases and positional parameters

start rabbitmqctl 'set_policy mirroring ^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$ {ha-mode:all}'
saps rabbitmqctl 'set_policy mirroring ^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$ {ha-mode:all}'
```

#### PS 3.0 and higher:

> ...you can use the `--%` operator which tells PowerShell to stop
>   parsing from that point onward until the end of the line. Everything
>   from that operator onwards is parsed by the parser used by the program.

```
rabbitmqctl --% set_policy mirroring ^(?!(?:amq\.)).+$ {ha-mode:all}
```

Reference:

- [PowerShell and external commands done right](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)

Comment: These didn't work as-is, but the issue was a result of how PS was passing in the args to rabbitmqctl so I'll mark it as the answer. I edited my question with the commands that worked for me. It is actually possible to run the command without passing an array, using Start-Process, or using `--%`.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't test it with `rabbitmqctl`, but `echoargs.exe` shows arguments as they should be. It probably has something to do with the way `rabbitmqctl` parses command line, because `cmd` should not be involved when PS passes arguments.

Comment: No problem. It got me on the right track. I updated my question with all the versions that worked for me.